# Where is blockchain located on Mac for Bitcoin-Qt?

Tags: bitcoin-core, backup, bitcoin-qt-setup

I attempted to use Bitcoin-Qt on my PC but it could not handle the Bitcoin blockchain. I therefore decided to give up and to delete the blockchain. Sadly, I cannot find where it is located.
I have looked up in ~/.bitcoin and ~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/ but to no avail. Where else could I find it?

Answer (score 4):

Quoting https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Data_directory#Mac :

> **Mac**
>
> By default Bitcoin will put its data here:
>
> > ~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/

You can access that folder by opening a new Finder window --> then by going to "Go" --> "Go to Folder..." (or pressing command + shift + G), and then pasting the above path into the window that appeared.

Answer (score 0):

Try to type into the Search window of the Finder "Bitcoin". Pretty sure you will see "Bitcoin QT" logo first in the list of the files found. Drag and drop it into the Trash folder and then empty it. The same way delete all the program files with "bitcoin" word in their names. It is not necessary that Library will contain the Bitcoin Core folder, that's why I uninstalled the Bitcoin Core app this way.